# Getting error when scheduling data load from command line

Tags: data-loader, automation, commandline

I'm running dataloader from command line. It is working fine when all my parameter like username, password are in "process-conf.xml" file.
Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="AccountExtract"
          class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
          singleton="false">
        <description>AccountMaster job gets the Customer record updates from ERP (Oracle financials) and uploads them to salesforce using 'upsert'.</description>
        <property name="name" value="AccountExtract"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="true"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="c:\dataloader\samples\status\accountMasterSoapTrace.log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://login.salesforce.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="user@mycompany.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="5555555555555555"/>
                <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="c:\dataloader\samples\conf\sample.key"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id,Name FROM Account limit 10"/>               
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="queryAccount"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

But when I'm using config.properties to store username and password, so that I can schedule this export, I'm getting below error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin>process.bat "c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig" AccountExtract

2016-05-30 16:35:56,638 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.j
ava:389) - Using built-in logging configuration, no log-conf.xml in C:\Program F
iles (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\log-conf.xml

2016-05-30 16:35:56,643 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.j
ava:391) - The log has been initialized

2016-05-30 16:35:56,648 INFO  [main] process.ProcessConfig getBeanFactory (Proce
ssConfig.java:103) - Loading process configuration from config file: c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig\process-conf.xml

2016-05-30 16:35:56,748 INFO  [main] xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinit
ions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315) - Loading XML bean definitions from file
 [c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig\process-conf.xml]

2016-05-30 16:35:56,798 ERROR [main] process.ProcessConfig getProcessInstance (P
rocessConfig.java:96) - Error loading process: AccountExtract configuration
from config file: c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig\process-conf.xml
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 i
n XML document from file [c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig\process-co
nf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The strin
g "--" is not permitted within comments.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFa
ctory.java:78)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFa
ctory.java:66)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getBeanFactory(Proces
sConfig.java:104)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getProcessInstance(Pr
ocessConfig.java:93)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.getInstance(ProcessRu
nner.java:287)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.getInstance(ProcessRu
nner.java:273)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.ja
va:246)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The string "--" is not permitted withi
n comments.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAX
ParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalErro
r(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanComment(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanComment(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unk
nown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocum
ent(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        ... 9 more
2016-05-30 16:35:56,923 FATAL [main] process.ProcessRunner topLevelError (Proces
sRunner.java:238) - Failed to create process
com.salesforce.dataloader.exception.ProcessInitializationException: Error loadin
g process: AccountExtract configuration from config file: c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig\process-conf.xml
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getProcessInstance(Pr
ocessConfig.java:97)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.getInstance(ProcessRu
nner.java:287)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.getInstance(ProcessRu
nner.java:273)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.ja
va:246)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException
: Line 20 in XML document from file [c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig
\process-conf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFa
ctory.java:78)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFa
ctory.java:66)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getBeanFactory(Proces
sConfig.java:104)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getProcessInstance(Pr
ocessConfig.java:93)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The string "--" is not permitted withi
n comments.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAX
ParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalErro
r(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanComment(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanComment(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unk
nown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocum
ent(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        ... 9 more
```

Config.properties:

```
#Loader Config
#Wed May 30 2016
sfdc.debugMessages=true
process.encryptionKeyFile=C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\Data Loader Documents\Try\Key.txt
sfdc.debugMessagesFile = C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\Data Loader Documents\Try\AccountExport.log
sfdc.endpoint=https://login.salesforce.com
sfdc.username=username@gmail.com
sfdc.password=7b5693f0cad856dc778d4b8506f2c976
sfdc.loadBatchSize=200
sfdc.timeoutSecs=600
```

process-conf.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="AccountExtract"
    class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
    singleton="false">
        <description>Export Account Data</description>
        <property name="name" value="AccountExtract"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sfdc.enableLastRunOutput" value="false"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Account"/>
            <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
            <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id,Name FROM Account limit 10"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig\extract.csv"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
            <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true" />
        </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Below is my command which I'm using:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin>process.bat "c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig" AccountExtract
```

I have gone through all the step present in below two blog but still getting error.:
https://gaganbansalblog4u.com/2013/08/11/cli-data-loader-through-command-prompt-salesforce/

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/tutorial-of-command-line-dataloader-salesforce/

Comment: the log says it is using this config file: `c:\dataloader\samples\conf\CLIconfig\process-conf.xml` - is that the one you are showing in the post or is it pointing at some other file?

Comment: Yes this is the process-conf file which i have posted here

Comment: I think it's picking up another config file as the error about -- in comments, and you have no comments in the file you've posted.